# What happens when two flames meet from opposite sides?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, science-in-society, dragons, fire

What happens when two flames (whether from dragons or blowtorches) meet head on? Many films make it appears as a front where the two flames repel each other, but my intuition is that, in fact, the two flames would continue as two waves on the surface of a lake.

In short, does anyone have sufficient scientific skills (or experience) to describe what happens when two flames of the same intensity impact directly opposite one another?

**Can a dragon block a fire attack with its own fire?**

[image]

Comment: The same thing as what happens when two streams of water collide.

Comment: @nzaman my question is precisly : Does the fire behave like waves? im not sure...

Comment: A flame is not a wave, it is a flow of hot gas. (That is to say, a flame is a material flow, like a river.) When two such flows intersect they may merge, or they may produce a highly turbulent flow, depending on flow speed and volume. One thing they won't do is pass through one another unmodified. P.S. What is a "chalumal"? Neither Google nor the Oxford English Dictionary know this word.

Comment: You could find out by yourself at home with two lit candles, two cans of spray and a friend.

Comment: @Renan no the flames of candle go to up ^^ I can't see very well :s

Comment: @Renan For safety concerns, do add fire-protective clothing, safety glasses, and so on. Otherwise, get a third friend to videotape what happens, post the thing on youtube, call 911 and watch the thing go viral for the next contenders for the Darwin award.

Comment: What is a "chalumal"? Are you mistranslating from French? possibly "blowtorch" < https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Blow_Torch_(3257353199).jpg >?

Comment: yes, I use google translate sry XD I will edit

Comment: This experiment could easily have answered your question. I haven't watched it all but you might be able to get some information from it - https://youtu.be/9_do_hnnXYE?t=291 - There is an instructional video by the same person who tells you how to make these flames so maybe you could try it!

Comment: Matrix, I edited your question for grammar and structure but I also made a very significant change.  You spoke of two flames *crossing* but your picture and other statements made it clear you really meant them meeting head on.  Crossing in the way you described it would imply the flames met at a 90° angle.  If my edit was wrong, please change it back.

Comment: no no it's good, i'm not speaking english very well ^^ good job thx ;)

Comment: This also is worth watching - https://youtu.be/ILA1ic-Q8_E?t=69

Comment: [Air–fuel ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air%E2%80%93fuel_ratio) - when you replace combustion air with fuel or vice versa, it goes out. If dragons use hyperbolic chemicals... IDK

Comment: I tried this at home using two cooking blowtorches and I can attest that you have a high probably of damage to your fingers. Don't try that at home.

Comment: @T.Sar - Oh, you used jet lighters? ha ha. Those have a way of keeping the air to fuel ratio just right; designed to be windproof.

Answer (score 36):

Flames are not waves, which can cross each other without perturbation.

Flames are basically flows of particles (the combustible) which are undergoing an energetic, exothermic reactions with the comburent (usually air Oxygen).

When the particle flows cross each other they will influence their respective motion, with a "simple" vectorial summation of their velocities, executed according to the principles of conservation of momentum and energy.

Comment: It's what I think too, but if we take 2 chalumals, what we can see? there is a projection of fire in each directions a half way ?

Comment: I edit question with image : the image is true or false according to the laws of physics ?

Comment: @Matrix, the only wrong part in the image is that the flame to not simply disappear. They would spread around more or less like a disk

Comment: @Matrix True, within reason. Some will pass through - nzaman's analogy of streams of water is a good one. Get two hoses (or similar) and point the jets at each other and see what happens.

Comment: I expect that they will mix rather more than that image suggests too although I have no evidence for that.

Comment: @TimB if the distance is large enough, it may be enough to protect completely, but not short-range, we agree?

Comment: @Matrix Too hard to say, someone would need to do the experiment (or look and see if anyone already did it).

Comment: @TimB: Part of a "blowdown" (for lack of a better name. I mean the thing in OP's image that often occurs in movies) is that the streams are projected with a tremendous force; and both opponents are equally matched in their aim and endurance. If one of them would be off target, the stream would deflect/veer off, rather than collide. The collision implies that they are (both) aiming exactly at each other and the only thing holding them back is the other's stream. In such a direct and precise collision, the visual effect of not mixing the two helps convey the dueling tug-of-war to the viewer.

Comment: @timb Whether they mix will depend on the substances involved. If both dragons are exhaling the same substance at the same temperature, they will likely mix some, but it’ll still mostly be disk-spread — it literally is a physical bounce of particles governing this effect. But different substances gets more complex. If they don’t react to each other, they may have less mixing because surface tension. And if they do react, they may create new chemicals and fly off at different angles.

Comment: The MythBusters tried something like this:  https://mythresults.com/fire-vs-ice

Comment: Okay, but what does a typical outcome look like? This does not appear to be an answer to the question.

Comment: @jpmc26, to attempt guessing the "typical outcome" one should provide the type of combustible, the medium in which they are moving, their relative velocity and then solve the Navier-Stokes equations for the system.

Comment: Then give some examples using fuels that you consider to be reasonable choices for the question at hand? Assume air as the medium, since the OP gives us a picture of flying creatures. And maybe just use stationary as an oversimplified starting point if motion is going too far. But put *some* kind of example in the answer.

Comment: @jpmc26, OP is nowhere asking that. OP is asking to "describe what happens when two flames of the same intensity impact directly opposite one another"

Comment: I'm not sure how you get that they're not asking for a description of what happens when it literally says "describe what happens." All I've suggested is *limiting* the description to a particular set of inputs to prevent this from becoming a 20 page paper.

Comment: The results of this is the stream with the greater inertia, that is the greater pressure mass or volume, wins. The heat of the flame has little effect. Of course you get a lot of splash as well. If you want to get a feel for it watch some fire fighter competitions where they "fight" with streams from firehoses.

Answer (score 15):

Fire is not "a thing" itself, but rather the rapid, exothermic oxidation of some material, normally gas (most or all liquids, that seem to burn are actually evaporating from the heat and only the gas burns).

So if two streams of fire meet, they will in most cases behave, like two colliding streams of gas. Unfortunately I do not seem to be able to find a simulation of this. But [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xYUQxIDwDOQ), you can see two streams of water collide. Gas will mostly look similar, but there will be more mixing of the two streams and more turbulences, resulting in a bigger cloud where they meet.

[edit: added from comment]
If angle, strength and surface are no exact match, but roughly right, it will still result in a lot of turbulences and most parts of the streams will disperse. But it quickly gets unpredictable and there may be small clouds of flame that reach one of the participants or cause collateral damage. If you watch the video, you will see, that the streams are not exactly the same. As a result, in the first 3 seconds the right source is hit by a blob of the left stream. After that, the streams reach an equilibrium. But this is partly because the sources are perfectly still.
[/edit]

This of course only works, if both streams are roughly the same size and power and directly colliding. If one is bigger or has more pressure or they hit each other at an angle, it starts to get complicated.

But in basic principle, yes, you can block a stream of fire with another stream of fire.

Comment: yes but we need have exactly the good angle, strength and surface of stream, so it's not realy realist no? In real life, it's impossible to have exactly all variables in good proportion at same time and maintain them over time...

Comment: If angle, strength and surface are no exact match, but roughly right, it will still result in a lot of turbulences and most parts of the streams will disperse. But it quickly gets unpredictable and there may be small clouds of flame that reach one of the participants or cause collateral damage. If you watch the video, you will see, that the streams are also not exactly the same. As a result, in the first 3 seconds the right source is hit by a blob of the left stream. After that, the streams reach an equilibrium. But this is partly because the sources are perfectly still.

Comment: Re, "Fire...only the gas burns." After a camp fire has burned down to a pile of glowing red charcoal, is that not still a "fire?"  (I know! I know! It's not exactly _dragon_ fire.)

Comment: @Till - sorry to be pedantic, but gas, as well as plasma (and obviously liquid) are all fluids! See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluid Otherwise, all good... :)

Comment: @JeremyDavis You're right. This was a translation error of me, since I'm not a native English speaker. I meant liquids.

Comment: @SolomonSlow "camp fire" is a term that has somewhat dispatched itself from the word fire. It has become somewhat of a thing itself. but I think, in the context of dragon fire and blowtorches, we can ignore that. And no, most people would not calling smouldering wood as being on fire. The exact definition of fire is a little imprecise on this though, hence my phrasing "some material, normally gas". But feel free, to add an analysation of the streams behaviour, if the dragons exhale glowing charcoal as "fiery breath", if you think that it improves the answer.

Comment: How does combustion work : oxidation +1. How does that work? : not a world building question.

Answer (score 5):

### It boils down to blocking a stream of gas with another stream of gas.

Fire happens when some sort of fuel undergoes combustion. With dragons this is usually presumed to be a flammable gas they are exhaling. The danger of such a fire comes from the combustion heating the gases that result from the combustion and other nearby gases to such a high temperature that they'll burn you or set you on fire if they touch you. So if you want to block a dragon's fire blast, you need to prevent that stream of very hot gases from touching you.

A simple experiment would be to have two people try to blow smoke into each other's faces at the same time. That should be a very rough approximation of what would happen. I suspect that the two streams actually would cancel out and become a cloud of smoke in the middle.

Answer (score -7):

Well since fire has no physical substance they should carry on through each other like, "two waves on the surface of a lake." However fire consumes oxygen so passing through where fire had just burn oxygen, they should both die immediately if in a confined space, while if they are outside, imaginable when two fire breathing creatures meet, then the fire should just lose some or most of its size, with anther possibility being that they will combine into one flame (it would depend on the speed of the fire). However if the fire was being created and maintained by a liquid fuel the effect would be near identical to that of which when water meets water head on.

Comment: Fire most definitely *has* a physical substance -- it's a flow of hot gas. Hot gas emits light just like any other hot body. Why would anybody believe that fire has no substance?

Comment: @AlexP The Rule of Cool has led to things like that, unfortunately.

Comment: @Renan possibly also a confusion on how the energy propogates? If you know that a ripple is nothing more than a virbration through a substance and heat is a vibration óf the substance you might confuse the two to be interchangeable. Which in part they even are as a ripple will leave some heat energy and heat energy will cause the surrounding material to start vibrating as it passes its energy. And if you then miss that the heat of the fire is an effect rather than the cause (which is the chemical reaction in exothermic fire) then this misconception is the result.

Comment: @Demigan Makes sense, but by Occam's razor I am still blaming cartoons and comics displaying battles of energy streams.